# CSS colors of the sections weren't filling up properly

Tags: html, css

This is the Css part of the page, i think it has something to do with the "contentwrap" class but i cant figure out how to fix it or why.

basically anything below the Featured Projects dosnt fill up with color all the way.

```css
/* global styles*/

.btn a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  color: #41463D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

body {
  color: #42463d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fffd98;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}

.contentwrap {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

header {
  background: #383B53;
  text-align: center;
  color: #C6C7C4;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

item-details h3+p {
  font-style: italic;
}

item-details h3~p {
  margin: 0;
}


/*profile/projects*/

.projects {
  background: #bee3db;
  padding: 8px
}

.projects a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.projects a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}

.project-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #222222;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.project-item img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.project-item {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*work*/

.work {
  padding: 8px;
}

.work a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.work a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}

.job-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
}


/*education*/

.learning a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.learning a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}


/*contact info*/

footer {
  background: #022B3A;
  color: #FFFAFA;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact-list a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>HermyCat/Slyzero</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <!-- ***********************  ABOUT / PROFILE  *********************** -->
  <header>
    <div class="contentwrap">


      <h1>HermyCat Slyzero</h1>
      <h2>CEO + Web Desinger</h2>

      <p>
        Add your profile copy here. Add more paragraphs or links as needed. Here is some dummy text: You act like you want me to be your friend and then you treat me like garbage. You’re pretty cute, you know that? Nancy, seriously, you're gonna be so cool now,
        it's ridiculous. No... no El, you're not the monster. You saved me. Do you understand? You saved me. You shouldn't like things because people tell you you're supposed to. If we’re both going crazy, then we’ll go crazy together, right? You’re going
        to take out the demigorgon with a slingshot? If anyone asks where I am, I've left the country. You’re going to take out the demigorgon with a slingshot?<a href="https://stranger-ipsum.robertcooper.me/">here is the stranger things lorem ipsum </a></p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- ********************  PROJECTS / PORTFOLIO  ********************* -->
  <section class="projects">
    <div class="contentwrap divider">
      <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
      <p>View selected projects below. More information can be found at <a href="http://christinatruong.com">christinatruong.com</a>.</p>

      <!-- Copy the whole <section> block to add more projects. -->
      <section class="project-item">


        <h2>So just SOme pictures i found :)</h2>

        <!-- picture 1-->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-2.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="le cofefe">
          <h3>le cofefee</h3>
          <p>Thestral dirigible plums, Viktor Krum hexed memory charm Animagus Invisibility Cloak three-headed Dog. Half-Blood Prince Invisibility Cloak cauldron cakes, hiya Harry! Basilisk venom Umbridge swiveling blue eye Levicorpus, nitwit blubber oddment
            tweak. Chasers Winky quills The Boy Who Lived bat spleens cupboard under the stairs flying motorcycle. Sirius Black Holyhead Harpies, you’ve got dirt on your nose. Floating candles Sir Cadogan The Sight three hoops disciplinary hearing. Grindlewald
            pig’s tail Sorcerer's Stone biting teacup. Side-along dragon-scale suits Filch 20 points, Mr. Potter."</p> <a href="http://www.christinachern.com/hpipsum/">Harry Potter Ipsum</a>
        </section>

        <!--pic 3 -->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-4.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="Books!">
          <h3>b00kS</h3>
          <p> kn0Wl@g3. Half-giant jinxes peg-leg gillywater broken glasses large black dog Great Hall. Nearly-Headless Nick now string them together, and answer me this, which creature would you be unwilling to kiss? Poltergeist sticking charm, troll umbrella
            stand flying cars golden locket Lily Potter. Pumpkin juice Trevor wave your wand out glass orbs, a Grim knitted hats. Stan Shunpike doe patronus, suck his soul Muggle-Born large order of drills the trace. Bred in captivity fell through the
            veil, quaffle blue flame ickle diddykins Aragog. Yer a wizard, Harry Doxycide the woes of Mrs. Weasley Goblet of Fire.</p>
        </section>
        <!--pic 4 -->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-5.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="The Golden Trio!">
          <h3>one of the most iconic trios in history</h3>
          <p>pOttAH-wEaZLE- and mUdblO0d</p>
          <p>
            Red hair crookshanks bludger Marauder’s Map Prongs sunshine daisies butter mellow Ludo Bagman. Beaters gobbledegook N.E.W.T., Honeydukes eriseD inferi Wormtail. Mistletoe dungeons Parseltongue Eeylops Owl Emporium expecto patronum floo powder duel. Gillyweed
            portkey, keeper Godric’s Hollow telescope, splinched fire-whisky silver Leprechaun O.W.L. stroke the spine. Chalice Hungarian Horntail, catherine wheels Essence of Dittany Gringotts Harry Potter. Prophecies Yaxley green eyes Remembrall horcrux
            hand of the servant. Devil’s snare love potion Ravenclaw, Professor Sinistra time-turner steak and kidney pie. Cabbage Daily Prophet letters from no one Dervish and Banges leg. Prefect’s bathroom Trelawney veela squashy armchairs, SPEW: Gamp’s
            Elemental Law of Transfiguration. Magic Nagini bezoar, Hippogriffs Headless Hunt giant squid petrified. Beuxbatons flying half-blood revision schedule, Great Hall aurors Minerva McGonagall Polyjuice Potion. Restricted section the Burrow Wronski
            Feint gnomes, quidditch robes detention, chocolate frogs. Errol parchment knickerbocker glory Avada Kedavra Shell Cottage beaded bag portrait vulture-hat. Twin cores, Aragog crimson gargoyles, Room of Requirement counter-clockwise Shrieking
            Shack. Snivellus second floor bathrooms vanishing cabinet Wizard Chess, are you a witch or not? Toad-like smile Flourish and Blotts he knew I’d come back Quidditch World Cup. Fat Lady baubles banana fritters fairy lights Petrificus Totalus.
            So thirsty, deluminator firs’ years follow me 12 inches of parchment. Head Boy start-of-term banquet Cleansweep Seven roaring lion hat. Unicorn blood crossbow mars is bright tonight, feast Norwegian Ridgeback. Come seek us where our voices
            sound, we cannot sing above the ground, Ginny Weasley bright red. Fanged frisbees, phoenix tears good clean match..
          </p>
        </section>

        <a href="file:///C:/Users/dilsh.DESKTOP-RKIOIBG/Desktop/Titanic/index.html" target="_blank">Heres My unfinished titanic project</a>

    </div>

    </section>
    <!-- End of Project block. -->
  </section ">
                      <div class="contentwrap ">
            
                          <!-- ***********************  WORK EXPERIENCE  *********************** -->
                          <section class="work ">
                              <div class="contentwrap item-details divider ">
            
                              <h2>Work Experience</h2>
                              <p>Kitty scratches couch bad kitty stare at imaginary bug sugar, my siamese, stalks me (in a good way), day and night pet my belly, you know you want to; seize the hand and shred it! and always ensure to lay down in such a manner that tail can lightly brush human's nose . Eat owner's food relentlessly pursues moth but inspect anything brought into the house fart in owners food yet eat from dog's food. Hide when guests come over weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed cat ass trophy. Why use post when this sofa is here pounce on unsuspecting person yet curl up and sleep on the freshly laundered towels. Hiiiiiiiiii feed me now get video posted to internet for chasing red dot yet stuff and things. Stand in front of the computer screen i show my fluffy belly but it's a trap! if you pet it i will tear up your hand have my breakfast spaghetti yarn or howl uncontrollably for no reason for then cats take over the world see owner, run in terror. Catto munch salmono ask for petting let me in let me out let me in let me out let me in let me out who broke this door anyway or rub butt on table so scratch at the door then walk away. Curl into a furry donut plan steps for world domination yet stinky cat, and when in doubt, wash, for this cat happen now, it was too purr-fect!!!. Chase red laser dot ask to go outside and ask to come inside and ask to go outside and ask to come inside mark territory, but lick sellotape yet really likes hummus hack up furballs. Burrow under covers hell is other people. Bite off human's toes chase mice.</p>
            
                              <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more jobs. -->
                              <section class="job-item ">
                                  <div class="job-details ">
                                      <h3>お前わも芯る, 何?!</h3>
                                      <p>Sweet Scents Shop</p>
                                      <p>I dunNo m8 wot</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="job-summary
      ">
                                      <p>
                                          the Hogwarts castle grounds blew wind that was magically intensified while the black sky rained blood. Meanwhile, in Hagrid's hut, all that was audible was his own furniture. Harry Potter thought magic was 'very good'. Rain fell like it was 'leathery sheets' on top of Harry's ghost as he walked the grounds. Ron stood there doing a tap dance, but once he saw Harry, he started eating Hermione's family. Ron's shirt of himself was just as bad as he was. Ron looked like a 'loud, slow, and soft bird' to Harry. He didn't like talking about even the subject of birds. Ron spotted Death Eaters on the castle roof, and was going to be 'spiders' but wasn't proud of it, knowing that he'd be covered in them anyway. Hermoine thought of the idea of listening to the Death Eaters' meetings, so the trio made their way to the castle roof door's landing. They almost ran in, but 'witches aren't climbing'. Ron then looked at the doorknob, then painfully at Hermoine, saying that the door was closed. Mr Staircase, a resident ghost, elaborated that it was actually locked, screaming at it's closedness and trying to ask it to substitute itself with an orb. Hermoine cried out the password: 'beef women'. The trio then stood behind a Death Eater circle, whose members looked 'bad'. Two Death Eaters kissed each other, one rather confidently, as the others clapped for them. They went over their plan to strip Harry of his magic, and Harry could tell that the Dark Lord was standing behind him, but he felt like he was overreacting. He ripped his eyes out of his head and threw them into the Forbidden Forest. Harry told Voldemort off, while Hermoine dipped the face on one of his Death Eaters, whom wore a 'Hermoine Has Forgotten How To Dance' shirt on him, in mud. Ron had thrown a wand at the Dark Lord while everyone gave applause, then slowly reached for his own while Harry reluctantly did the same, casting a spell or two while green light shot out of the heads of the Death Eaters. Ron flinched afterwards. Harry thought 'Not so handsome now' as he dipped Hermoine in hot sauce. The Death Eaters were dead, having recently been killed by him and Ron, and Harry was hungrier than he'd ever been. Meanwhile, in the Great Hall, moaning chandeliers filled the hall, along with a large librarian whom used the masonry books as decorations. Mice mountains exploded, and long pumpkins fell off McGonagall. Dumbledore's hair then went next to Hermoine as he arrived at the school. The Hufflepuff pig pulsed like a bullfrog, and Dumbledore, smiling at it and having placed his hand on it's head, told it that it was Hagrid now. The trio said together that 'they were the only ones that mattered, and he's never going to get rid of us.' The castle floor seemed to be a big magic pile, and the Dursleys weren't ever gonna be there. Harry then looked around and fell down the staircase for the whole summer, afterwards exclaiming 'I'm Harry Potter. The dark arts better be worried, oh boy!" </p>
  </div>



  </section>
  <!--JOB 2 JUST LIKE, FYI. -->
  <section class="job-item">
    <div class="job-details">
      <h3>Spill the tea sis</h3>
      <p>Stylenectix</p>
      <p>what is this ominous messsage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-summary">
      <p>
        Furrier and even more furrier hairball pet right here, no not there, here, no fool, right here that other cat smells funny you should really give me all the treats because i smell the best and omg you finally got the right spot and i love you right now
        for go into a room to decide you didn't want to be in there anyway yet then cats take over the world for i love cuddles for twitch tail in permanent irritation. Decide to want nothing to do with my owner today hunt by meowing loudly at 5am next
        to human slave food dispenser or cat walks in keyboard for hunt anything that moves, or drink water out of the faucet poop in the plant pot. Stare out cat door then go back inside good morning sunshine sleep everywhere, but not in my bed but stretch
        claw at curtains stretch and yawn nibble on tuna ignore human bite human hand. Steal mom's crouton while she is in the bathroom oooo! dangly balls! jump swat swing flies so sweetly to the floor crash move on wash belly nap pee in human's bed until
        he cleans the litter box knock over christmas tree plays league of legends so i bet my nine lives on you-oooo-ooo-hooo. I can haz a nice warm laptop for me to sit on the door is opening! how exciting oh, it's you, meh meow all night having their
        mate disturbing sleeping humans. Cat sit like bread my left donut is missing, as is my right yet demand to be let outside at once, and expect owner to wait for me as i think about it. Stand in front of the computer screen sniff all the things
        or sniff other cat's butt and hang jaw half open thereafter purr like a car engine oh yes, there is my human slave woman she does best pats ever that all i like about her hiss meow and rub butt on table. A nice warm laptop for me to sit on. Spit
        up on light gray carpet instead of adjacent linoleum intrigued by the shower chew iPad power cord, for love you, then bite you yet cry louder at reflection.
      </p>
    </div>

  </section>
  <!------------JOB 3 -------------->
  <section class="job-item">
    <div class="job-details">
      <h3>No, brittney you arn't quirky beacuse you like pizza</h3>
      <p>Titanic</p>
      <p>HA HA FOOLS YOU HAVE FALLEN INTO MY DEATHTRAP- NOW YOU SHALL PAY THE PRICEEEE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-summary">
      <p>
        Shove bum in owner's face like camera lens get suspicious of own shadow then go play with toilette paper cats secretly make all the worlds muffins trip owner up in kitchen i want food or scratch leg; meow for can opener to feed me cats making all the
        muffins. Play riveting piece on synthesizer keyboard need to check on human, have not seen in an hour might be dead oh look, human is alive, hiss at human, feed me attack feet, yet being gorgeous with belly side up. If human is on laptop sit on
        the keyboard playing with balls of wool for poop on grasses. Murder hooman toes. Hiss and stare at nothing then run suddenly away warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats. Prance along on
        top of the garden fence, annoy the neighbor's dog and make it bark i'm going to lap some water out of my master's cup meow a nice warm laptop for me to sit on take a big fluffing crap  find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day, yet meoooow
        for cough hairball, eat toilet paper. Sniff all the things the best thing in the universe is a cardboard box for hunt anything that moves. Dead stare with ears cocked hack sleep for eat owner's food litter box is life, sleep all day whilst slave
        is at work, play all night whilst slave is sleeping. Stare at guinea pigs cat cat moo moo lick ears lick paws yet being gorgeous with belly side up.

      </p>
    </div>



    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- End of Job block. -->
  </section>

  <!-- ******************  EDUCATION & CERTIFICATIONS ****************** -->
  <section class="education">
    <div class="contentwrap item-details">
      <h2>Education</h2>

      <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more schools. -->
      <section class="learning">
        <h3>Hogwarts School of witchcraft and wizardry - Slytherin</h3>
        <p>Designation received or program name, year attended</p>
        <p>Summary or accomplishments.</p>
        <h2>Quarantine is getting to me so i'm learning the first 100 digits of pi</h2>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CDqLIEp-ojo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDqLIEp-ojo" class="btn"> if video dosnt work then click here</a>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End of School block. -->
  </section>

  <!-- *****************  CONTACT INFO / SOCIAL MEDIA  ***************** -->
  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

      <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
      <ul class="contact-list">
        <li><a class="btn" href="http://yourwebsite.com" target="_blank">yourwebsite.com</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Click edit, scroll  then click edit above snippet - you will see your HTML in invalid. For one you have a quote in your `</section ">`

Comment: Can you please just post the part of the code that leads to the problem? And descripe more accurately what thet problem exactly is. It's really hard to find a mistake on a whole page including lots of text if we are not even sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Was this what you where looking for? You incorrectly closed your section and moved the position to end the section at the right place. Of course depending on your wishes for the desired result, but it matches your question to let the background color fill all the way down.

I've changed:

```
    </div>
    <!-- End of Project block. -->
  </section ">
```

To:

```
 </section>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Project block. -->
```

```css
/* global styles*/

.btn a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  color: #41463D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

body {
  color: #42463d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fffd98;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}

.contentwrap {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

header {
  background: #383B53;
  text-align: center;
  color: #C6C7C4;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

item-details h3+p {
  font-style: italic;
}

item-details h3~p {
  margin: 0;
}


/*profile/projects*/

.projects {
  background: #bee3db;
  padding: 8px
}

.projects a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.projects a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}

.project-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #222222;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.project-item img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.project-item {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*work*/

.work {
  padding: 8px;
}

.work a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.work a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}

.job-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  column-gap: 20px;
}


/*education*/

.learning a {
  color: #FFFAFA;
  background: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.learning a:hover {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 80%);
}


/*contact info*/

footer {
  background: #022B3A;
  color: #FFFAFA;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact-list a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>HermyCat/Slyzero</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<main>
  <!-- ***********************  ABOUT / PROFILE  *********************** -->
  <header>
    <div class="contentwrap">
      <h1>HermyCat Slyzero</h1>
      <h2>CEO + Web Desinger</h2>
      
      <p>Add your profile copy here. Add more paragraphs or links as needed. Here is some dummy text: You act like you want me to be your friend and then you treat me like garbage. You’re pretty cute, you know that? Nancy, seriously, you're gonna be so cool
        now, it's ridiculous. No... no El, you're not the monster. You saved me. Do you understand? You saved me. You shouldn't like things because people tell you you're supposed to. If we’re both going crazy, then we’ll go crazy together, right? You’re
        going to take out the demigorgon with a slingshot? If anyone asks where I am, I've left the country. You’re going to take out the demigorgon with a slingshot?<a href="https://stranger-ipsum.robertcooper.me/">here is the stranger things lorem ipsum </a></p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- ********************  PROJECTS / PORTFOLIO  ********************* -->
  <section class="projects">
    <div class="contentwrap divider">
      <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
      <p>View selected projects below. More information can be found at <a href="http://christinatruong.com">christinatruong.com</a>.</p>

      <!-- Copy the whole <section> block to add more projects. -->
      <section class="project-item">


        <h2>So just SOme pictures i found :)</h2>

        <!-- picture 1-->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-2.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="le cofefe">
          <h3>le cofefee</h3>
          <p>Thestral dirigible plums, Viktor Krum hexed memory charm Animagus Invisibility Cloak three-headed Dog. Half-Blood Prince Invisibility Cloak cauldron cakes, hiya Harry! Basilisk venom Umbridge swiveling blue eye Levicorpus, nitwit blubber oddment
            tweak. Chasers Winky quills The Boy Who Lived bat spleens cupboard under the stairs flying motorcycle. Sirius Black Holyhead Harpies, you’ve got dirt on your nose. Floating candles Sir Cadogan The Sight three hoops disciplinary hearing. Grindlewald
            pig’s tail Sorcerer's Stone biting teacup. Side-along dragon-scale suits Filch 20 points, Mr. Potter."</p> <a href="http://www.christinachern.com/hpipsum/">Harry Potter Ipsum</a>
        </section>

        <!--pic 3 -->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-4.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="Books!">
          <h3>b00kS</h3>
          <p> kn0Wl@g3. Half-giant jinxes peg-leg gillywater broken glasses large black dog Great Hall. Nearly-Headless Nick now string them together, and answer me this, which creature would you be unwilling to kiss? Poltergeist sticking charm, troll umbrella
            stand flying cars golden locket Lily Potter. Pumpkin juice Trevor wave your wand out glass orbs, a Grim knitted hats. Stan Shunpike doe patronus, suck his soul Muggle-Born large order of drills the trace. Bred in captivity fell through the
            veil, quaffle blue flame ickle diddykins Aragog. Yer a wizard, Harry Doxycide the woes of Mrs. Weasley Goblet of Fire.</p>
        </section>
        <!--pic 4 -->
        <section class="project-item">
          <img src="img/thumbnail-5.jpg" width="320" height="261" alt="The Golden Trio!">
          <h3>one of the most iconic trios in history</h3>
          <p>pOttAH-wEaZLE- and mUdblO0d</p>
          <p>
            Red hair crookshanks bludger Marauder’s Map Prongs sunshine daisies butter mellow Ludo Bagman. Beaters gobbledegook N.E.W.T., Honeydukes eriseD inferi Wormtail. Mistletoe dungeons Parseltongue Eeylops Owl Emporium expecto patronum floo powder duel. Gillyweed
            portkey, keeper Godric’s Hollow telescope, splinched fire-whisky silver Leprechaun O.W.L. stroke the spine. Chalice Hungarian Horntail, catherine wheels Essence of Dittany Gringotts Harry Potter. Prophecies Yaxley green eyes Remembrall horcrux
            hand of the servant. Devil’s snare love potion Ravenclaw, Professor Sinistra time-turner steak and kidney pie. Cabbage Daily Prophet letters from no one Dervish and Banges leg. Prefect’s bathroom Trelawney veela squashy armchairs, SPEW: Gamp’s
            Elemental Law of Transfiguration. Magic Nagini bezoar, Hippogriffs Headless Hunt giant squid petrified. Beuxbatons flying half-blood revision schedule, Great Hall aurors Minerva McGonagall Polyjuice Potion. Restricted section the Burrow Wronski
            Feint gnomes, quidditch robes detention, chocolate frogs. Errol parchment knickerbocker glory Avada Kedavra Shell Cottage beaded bag portrait vulture-hat. Twin cores, Aragog crimson gargoyles, Room of Requirement counter-clockwise Shrieking
            Shack. Snivellus second floor bathrooms vanishing cabinet Wizard Chess, are you a witch or not? Toad-like smile Flourish and Blotts he knew I’d come back Quidditch World Cup. Fat Lady baubles banana fritters fairy lights Petrificus Totalus.
            So thirsty, deluminator firs’ years follow me 12 inches of parchment. Head Boy start-of-term banquet Cleansweep Seven roaring lion hat. Unicorn blood crossbow mars is bright tonight, feast Norwegian Ridgeback. Come seek us where our voices
            sound, we cannot sing above the ground, Ginny Weasley bright red. Fanged frisbees, phoenix tears good clean match..
          </p>
        </section>

        <a href="file:///C:/Users/dilsh.DESKTOP-RKIOIBG/Desktop/Titanic/index.html" target="_blank">Heres My unfinished titanic project</a>
 </section>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Project block. -->
                      <div class="contentwrap ">
            
                          <!-- ***********************  WORK EXPERIENCE  *********************** -->
                          <section class="work ">
                              <div class="contentwrap item-details divider ">
            
                              <h2>Work Experience</h2>
                              <p>Kitty scratches couch bad kitty stare at imaginary bug sugar, my siamese, stalks me (in a good way), day and night pet my belly, you know you want to; seize the hand and shred it! and always ensure to lay down in such a manner that tail can lightly brush human's nose . Eat owner's food relentlessly pursues moth but inspect anything brought into the house fart in owners food yet eat from dog's food. Hide when guests come over weigh eight pounds but take up a full-size bed cat ass trophy. Why use post when this sofa is here pounce on unsuspecting person yet curl up and sleep on the freshly laundered towels. Hiiiiiiiiii feed me now get video posted to internet for chasing red dot yet stuff and things. Stand in front of the computer screen i show my fluffy belly but it's a trap! if you pet it i will tear up your hand have my breakfast spaghetti yarn or howl uncontrollably for no reason for then cats take over the world see owner, run in terror. Catto munch salmono ask for petting let me in let me out let me in let me out let me in let me out who broke this door anyway or rub butt on table so scratch at the door then walk away. Curl into a furry donut plan steps for world domination yet stinky cat, and when in doubt, wash, for this cat happen now, it was too purr-fect!!!. Chase red laser dot ask to go outside and ask to come inside and ask to go outside and ask to come inside mark territory, but lick sellotape yet really likes hummus hack up furballs. Burrow under covers hell is other people. Bite off human's toes chase mice.</p>
            
                              <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more jobs. -->
                              <section class="job-item ">
                                  <div class="job-details ">
                                      <h3>お前わも芯る, 何?!</h3>
                                      <p>Sweet Scents Shop</p>
                                      <p>I dunNo m8 wot</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="job-summary
      ">
                                      <p>
                                          the Hogwarts castle grounds blew wind that was magically intensified while the black sky rained blood. Meanwhile, in Hagrid's hut, all that was audible was his own furniture. Harry Potter thought magic was 'very good'. Rain fell like it was 'leathery sheets' on top of Harry's ghost as he walked the grounds. Ron stood there doing a tap dance, but once he saw Harry, he started eating Hermione's family. Ron's shirt of himself was just as bad as he was. Ron looked like a 'loud, slow, and soft bird' to Harry. He didn't like talking about even the subject of birds. Ron spotted Death Eaters on the castle roof, and was going to be 'spiders' but wasn't proud of it, knowing that he'd be covered in them anyway. Hermoine thought of the idea of listening to the Death Eaters' meetings, so the trio made their way to the castle roof door's landing. They almost ran in, but 'witches aren't climbing'. Ron then looked at the doorknob, then painfully at Hermoine, saying that the door was closed. Mr Staircase, a resident ghost, elaborated that it was actually locked, screaming at it's closedness and trying to ask it to substitute itself with an orb. Hermoine cried out the password: 'beef women'. The trio then stood behind a Death Eater circle, whose members looked 'bad'. Two Death Eaters kissed each other, one rather confidently, as the others clapped for them. They went over their plan to strip Harry of his magic, and Harry could tell that the Dark Lord was standing behind him, but he felt like he was overreacting. He ripped his eyes out of his head and threw them into the Forbidden Forest. Harry told Voldemort off, while Hermoine dipped the face on one of his Death Eaters, whom wore a 'Hermoine Has Forgotten How To Dance' shirt on him, in mud. Ron had thrown a wand at the Dark Lord while everyone gave applause, then slowly reached for his own while Harry reluctantly did the same, casting a spell or two while green light shot out of the heads of the Death Eaters. Ron flinched afterwards. Harry thought 'Not so handsome now' as he dipped Hermoine in hot sauce. The Death Eaters were dead, having recently been killed by him and Ron, and Harry was hungrier than he'd ever been. Meanwhile, in the Great Hall, moaning chandeliers filled the hall, along with a large librarian whom used the masonry books as decorations. Mice mountains exploded, and long pumpkins fell off McGonagall. Dumbledore's hair then went next to Hermoine as he arrived at the school. The Hufflepuff pig pulsed like a bullfrog, and Dumbledore, smiling at it and having placed his hand on it's head, told it that it was Hagrid now. The trio said together that 'they were the only ones that mattered, and he's never going to get rid of us.' The castle floor seemed to be a big magic pile, and the Dursleys weren't ever gonna be there. Harry then looked around and fell down the staircase for the whole summer, afterwards exclaiming 'I'm Harry Potter. The dark arts better be worried, oh boy!" </p>
  </div>

    </section>


  <!--JOB 2 JUST LIKE, FYI. -->
  <section class="job-item">
    <div class="job-details">
      <h3>Spill the tea sis</h3>
      <p>Stylenectix</p>
      <p>what is this ominous messsage</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-summary">
      <p>
        Furrier and even more furrier hairball pet right here, no not there, here, no fool, right here that other cat smells funny you should really give me all the treats because i smell the best and omg you finally got the right spot and i love you right now
        for go into a room to decide you didn't want to be in there anyway yet then cats take over the world for i love cuddles for twitch tail in permanent irritation. Decide to want nothing to do with my owner today hunt by meowing loudly at 5am next
        to human slave food dispenser or cat walks in keyboard for hunt anything that moves, or drink water out of the faucet poop in the plant pot. Stare out cat door then go back inside good morning sunshine sleep everywhere, but not in my bed but stretch
        claw at curtains stretch and yawn nibble on tuna ignore human bite human hand. Steal mom's crouton while she is in the bathroom oooo! dangly balls! jump swat swing flies so sweetly to the floor crash move on wash belly nap pee in human's bed until
        he cleans the litter box knock over christmas tree plays league of legends so i bet my nine lives on you-oooo-ooo-hooo. I can haz a nice warm laptop for me to sit on the door is opening! how exciting oh, it's you, meh meow all night having their
        mate disturbing sleeping humans. Cat sit like bread my left donut is missing, as is my right yet demand to be let outside at once, and expect owner to wait for me as i think about it. Stand in front of the computer screen sniff all the things
        or sniff other cat's butt and hang jaw half open thereafter purr like a car engine oh yes, there is my human slave woman she does best pats ever that all i like about her hiss meow and rub butt on table. A nice warm laptop for me to sit on. Spit
        up on light gray carpet instead of adjacent linoleum intrigued by the shower chew iPad power cord, for love you, then bite you yet cry louder at reflection.
      </p>
    </div>

  </section>
  <!------------JOB 3 -------------->
  <section class="job-item">
    <div class="job-details">
      <h3>No, brittney you arn't quirky beacuse you like pizza</h3>
      <p>Titanic</p>
      <p>HA HA FOOLS YOU HAVE FALLEN INTO MY DEATHTRAP- NOW YOU SHALL PAY THE PRICEEEE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="job-summary">
      <p>
        Shove bum in owner's face like camera lens get suspicious of own shadow then go play with toilette paper cats secretly make all the worlds muffins trip owner up in kitchen i want food or scratch leg; meow for can opener to feed me cats making all the
        muffins. Play riveting piece on synthesizer keyboard need to check on human, have not seen in an hour might be dead oh look, human is alive, hiss at human, feed me attack feet, yet being gorgeous with belly side up. If human is on laptop sit on
        the keyboard playing with balls of wool for poop on grasses. Murder hooman toes. Hiss and stare at nothing then run suddenly away warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats. Prance along on
        top of the garden fence, annoy the neighbor's dog and make it bark i'm going to lap some water out of my master's cup meow a nice warm laptop for me to sit on take a big fluffing crap  find empty spot in cupboard and sleep all day, yet meoooow
        for cough hairball, eat toilet paper. Sniff all the things the best thing in the universe is a cardboard box for hunt anything that moves. Dead stare with ears cocked hack sleep for eat owner's food litter box is life, sleep all day whilst slave
        is at work, play all night whilst slave is sleeping. Stare at guinea pigs cat cat moo moo lick ears lick paws yet being gorgeous with belly side up.

      </p>
    </div>

  </section>

  <!-- End of Job block. -->


  <!-- ******************  EDUCATION & CERTIFICATIONS ****************** -->
  <section class="education">
    <div class="contentwrap item-details">
      <h2>Education</h2>

      <!-- Copy this whole <section> block to add more schools. -->
      <section class="learning">
        <h3>Hogwarts School of witchcraft and wizardry - Slytherin</h3>
        <p>Designation received or program name, year attended</p>
        <p>Summary or accomplishments.</p>
        <h2>Quarantine is getting to me so i'm learning the first 100 digits of pi</h2>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CDqLIEp-ojo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDqLIEp-ojo" class="btn"> if video dosnt work then click here</a>
          </section>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End of School block. -->
  </section>

  <!-- *****************  CONTACT INFO / SOCIAL MEDIA  ***************** -->
  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Let's Keep in Touch!</h2>

      <!-- Social media and contact links. Add or remove any networks. -->
      <ul class="contact-list">
        <li><a class="btn" href="http://yourwebsite.com" target="_blank">yourwebsite.com</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</main>
```